# Kripke $S5$ system on game theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My question is short, but reaching that point is going to take some time. Sorry about that in advance. 
Take $\Omega$ as finite and $K:2^{\Omega}\to 2^{\Omega}$ be an operator with following properties:

- $K(\Omega)=\Omega$;
- $K(A)\cap K(B)=K(A\cap B)$;
- $K(A)\subseteq A$ for every $A\subseteq \Omega$;
- $K(K(A))=K(A)$;
- $(K(A))^{c}=K((K(A))^c)$

Define $F(\omega)=\bigcap\left\{A\subseteq\Omega,\omega\in K(A) \right\}$. Finally the question is,

Prove that $\omega\in F(\omega)$ for each $\omega \in \Omega$.

This seems very intuitive and clear, however I can't write the proof rigorously. The main reason is I am not sure if I understand the meaning of $F(\omega)$. Any help, or better proof, would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If $\omega \in K(A)$, $\omega \in A$ since $K(A) \subset A$. So $\omega \in A$ for all $\omega \in K(A)$. And since $\sigma$ is finite, $\omega \in F(\omega)$ (finite intersection) for all $\omega$.

Is there more to this question?

Comment: Yes. If $\omega^{\prime}\in F(\omega)$ then $F(\omega)=F(\omega^{\prime})$. By the way I don't understand your solution. How do you understand $F(\omega)$ intersection of sets or intersection of $\omega$s?

Comment: $F(\omega)$ is the intersection of sets for which $\omega$ is contained in their image (under K).

Answer (score 0):

Since $F(\omega) = \bigcap\{A\subseteq \Omega: \omega\in K(A)\}$, in order to show $\omega\in F(\omega)$ it suffices to show that for all $A\subseteq \Omega$ such that $\omega \in K(A)$, $\omega\in A$.

So suppose $A\subseteq \Omega$ and $\omega \in K(\omega)$. Then, since $K(A) \subseteq A$, it follows that $\omega \in A$, as required. Since $A$ was arbitrary, this holds for all $A\subseteq \Omega$ with $\omega\in K(A)$.